# Zookeeper acl to allow any authenticated user

Tags: authentication, apache-zookeeper, acl

I want to use custom login module on zookeeper and then allow any authenticated user who has the ability to log in to do any action on the znode. How would I go about that?

```
setAcl /znode auth:crdwa
```

is not a valid acl assignment. If there is no other way than to specify usernames, can I at least set the acl without specifying the password? Something like:

```
setAcl /znode auth:user:crdwa
```

I want the authentication to be taken care of using the custom login module.

Answer (score 0):

correct example of zookeeper acl in zkCli would be:

First let's generate password:

```
java -cp zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar    org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestAuthenticationProvider u1:p1
u1:p1->u1:fpT/y03U+EjItKZOSLGvjnJlyng=
```

In zkCli session let's authenticate:

```
addauth digest u1:p1
```

Then let's set ACL to some node:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 14] setAcl /someZNode digest:u1:fpT/y03U+EjItKZOSLGvjnJlyng=:crdwa
```

If it's planned to use custom login module then AuthenticationProvider should be implemented according to [Pluggable Zookeeper Authentication](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.5/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_ZooKeeperPluggableAuthentication) and jar file with implementation class should be placed into {zookeeperDir}/lib directory

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this, I asked whether there is another way of doing that without having to specify the login information within the ACL, relying upon the authentication information provided within the jaas.